# Facebook Login w/ Java Web

Tags: java, facebook

I'm trying to implement a Facebook login for my site and am having a world of trouble. I understand the difference between the client (JavaScript SDK) and server-side implementations, but am confused as to which is the correct approach. What I need is to store the user's info in my database (userID, email, name, etc.), so I know I'll need the data on the server side. I don't want to log in via the JS SDK and send the data to the back end because it can easily be spoofed, so here's what I tried:

I've tried using the SDK and, once the user is logged in, refreshing the page to check for the cookie that Facebook puts in the session, but it doesn't seem to be present; the only cookie that's there is the session id.

Additionally, I tried doing a server-side implementation, but this caused the Facebook log in screen to be in the main browser window instead of a popup. This is undesirable because it takes the user away from my site. To force the login workflow to be in a separate window, I've thought about popping up a child window that points to my login url that ultimately redirects to Facebook, but then I don't know when the user is done logging in (I'd need to refresh the main page to hide the facebook login button, etc.).

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated! I'd like to do this the right way... not the easy way!

Comment: Could you please update the question with the solution that you chose Spring Social and Why .. thanks.

Comment: Check out my response to my answer. I followed those examples to a T (with minor tweaks specific to my site). I chose spring-social because the implementation makes it incredibly simple to connect to facebook and use the graph api. It also integrates pretty nicely with springsecurity, which is shown in the post I linked to in my response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line: use [spring-social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social) in java applications for connection to the social networks. It's cake!

Comment: The [spring-social documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html#service-providers-oauth2) on oauth2 is a good starting point. To integrate with spring-security I found [this post](http://blog.trickl.com/?tag=spring-social) very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official Facebook API for standard Java that I am aware of. Specifically for Facebook, your java app can use the REST API here http://restfb.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I went with spring-social in the end. Restfb doesn't actually handle the login mechanism - it's left up to you. Once you are logged in, restfb becomes useful. Spring-social, on the other hand, handles the login mechanism, integrates nicely with spring-security, and also provides a facade for the various fb, twitter, etc. functions.